# Is my jquery selector wrong?

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, tooltip

I´m trying to create a tooltip with a list inside, this list is supposed to be selectable, so I´m using the code from the next wbepage: http://3nhanced.com/javascript/simple-tooltip-powered-by-jquery/
to create my tooltip, but when I use the next code to create the selectable item:

```
    $(document).ready(function() {

        $('.toolTip').hover(
            function() {
                this.tip = this.title;
                console.log($(this));
                $(this).append(
                    '<div class="toolTipWrapper">'
                        +'<div class="toolTipTop"></div>'
                        +'<div class="toolTipMid">'
                            +'<ul id="selectable">'
                                +'<li class="ui-widget-content">Item</li>'
                                +'<li class="ui-widget-content">Item</li>'
                            +'</ul>'                                            
                        +'</div>'
                        +'<div class="toolTipBtm"></div>'
                    +'</div>'
                );
                this.title = "";
                this.width = $(this).width();
                $(this).find('.toolTipWrapper').css({left:this.width-22})
                $('.toolTipWrapper').fadeIn(300);
            },
            function() {
                $('.toolTipWrapper').fadeOut(100);
                $(this).children().remove();
                this.title = this.tip;
            }
        );


        $("#selectable").selectable({
            stop: function() {
                var $item2 = $(this),
                $target = $(event.target);
                console.log($target);                   
                var result = $("#select-result").empty();
                $(".ui-selected", this).each(function() {
                    var index = $("#selectable li" ).index(this);
                    result.append(" #" + (index + 1));
                });
            }
        });         
});
```

Does anyone has an idea why it´s not working?
As everyone can see; the toolltipcreation is being done first before using the selectable function.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Slightly off-topic: Are you creating/attaching and destroying a div every time you hover over/off something?  Wouldn't it be easier for the div to already exist and hide/show it?

Answer (score 2):

The code inside `$(function() {...});` runs when the DOM is ready. However, you're inserting your `<ul id="selectable">` later on, using the `.append()` function, so the element **doesn't exist** when your first section of code runs.

You'll need to run that code after inserting your additional HTML.

Comment: @linker85 Still seems like it's going to be a problem with the order in which you call each of the sections of code. Make sure the `$( "#selectable" ).selectable({...});` section is **after** the part that appends the elements.

Comment: Ok I solve it by putting the selectable function inside the hover function.

Answer (score 1):

You have to call `$("#selectable").selectable(...)` when the element actually exists. In other words, after you've created the tooltip.

Comment: Doesn´t that happens when i have the creation of my tooltip and the selectable function inside the $(document).onready funtcion???